# RHEL 7.1 Virtual Terminal

Tags: rhel, xorg

I am looking to disable the Virtual Terminals on a RHEL 7.1 laptop.  All of the instructions I have found point me to adding

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "DontVTSwitch" "true"
EndSection
```

to the `xorg.conf` file.

This is all well and good, except that RHEL 7.1 does not have an `xorg.conf` file, instead breaking it into a config directory that currently contains one file: `00-keyboard.conf`.  If I add the `ServerFlags` to this file, the consoles are disabled.  Success!

BUT this does not seem like the correct way to do this (or is it? that is why I am asking).  Where should I be adding the `ServerFlags` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `xorg.conf.d` is just to allow you to separate unrelated config stanzas into different files, while having them all apply. Anything written in any of them will be parsed, just as if all of them had been concatenated into one `xorg.conf`. It's fine to put your addition into `00-keyboard.conf` (seeing as it does deal with the keyboard, sort of), or you could make a new file in the same directory (`10-novtswitch.conf`, maybe) and put it there.